# Remotely running malware detection on a *unix server

Tags: linux, unix, webserver, malware

I've used [Linux Malware Detect](https://www.rfxn.com/projects/linux-malware-detect/) in the past and it's very efficient and useful, however to run the installation shell script access to the root directory is required.

As a result, when I'm on many shared hosting servers I can't install it and run a scan. Instead, I have to `rsync` the directories I want to scan to a different machine, then run a scan, remove the malware and transfer back.

This makes the process significantly longer than it should be and impractical for some large scans. Unfortunately the [Maldetect documentation](https://www.rfxn.com/appdocs/README.maldetect) doesn't mention anything about scanning remotely.

Any ideas on how this could be accomplished or an alternate similar tool I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could instead run your malware scan on a local machine or VM with SSHFS access to the remote filesystem - SSHFS is a FUSE filesystem that turns SCP into a local folder so your malware scan doesn't need to transfer the files before and after.

Comment: Thanks! SSHFS is what I was hoping for as a bridge solution but I didn't know if something like that existed. Once I test it out I'll check yours as the answer.

Comment: SSHFS does have some very odd behaviour so it *may* not work for everything but it did work for a surprisingly high percent of anything I did try it for.

Comment: Seems to be working great for this purpose, at least so far. Thanks!